# Loading XML file throwing a RuntimeException

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android, layout-inflater

I'm using the following XML file for creating a layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80px">
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
      android:layout_marginTop="10px">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAirLineCodeLv"
        android:text="TextView" />
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/StopDetailBtnLv"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPriceLv"
        android:text="TextView" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imgFlightLogoLv" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearText2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtTotalDurationLv"
         android:text="TextView" />
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/txtStopCountLv"
      android:text="TextView" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearText3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtOrgLv"
        android:text="TextView" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I load this file by using a following code:

```
view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomizeSearchResult, parent, false) as LinearLayout;
```

a `RuntimeException` is thrown. I think I have problem in the layout but I'm not able to find that. Because when I load another XML file in place of that, then no error is showed and it run successfully.

Comment: Is it valid? `as` operator?  `view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CustomizeSearchResult, parent, false) as LinearLayout;`

Comment: hi spk,i am new on andriod platform therefore i dont know the use logCat

Comment: @AVd =i am using mono for android and my code is in c# and it works with another layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you did not set the `height` and `weight` to the `ImageView` and `TextView`.

Graphic layout will be visible to you if you give proper `height and weight` to the UI Elements.

If you want to set the height and weight to the UI elements programmatically, you can set the height and weight using java. You need not worry about the sizes given in the `XML` layout.

I am sure these height and weight will be changed at **runtime**.

change your xml as like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/widget28"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="80px">
  <LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/linearText"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
   android:layout_marginTop="10px">
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAirLineCodeLv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/StopDetailBtnLv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPriceLv"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearText1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imgFlightLogoLv" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearText2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtTotalDurationLv"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="TextView" />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txtStopCountLv"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearText3"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/txtOrgLv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the layout_height and layout_width for TextViews and ImageView

Comment: i give layout heigh and weidth at run time